# Static data storage on server-side

Tags: azerothcore

Why some data on server-side are still stored in DBC files, not in SQL-DB? In particular - spells (spells.dbc). What for?
We have a lot of bugs in spells and it's very hard to understand what's wrong with spell, but it's harder to find it spell...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is commentary and discussion and not a specific programming problem and question.

Answer (score 2):

Spells, Talents, achievements, etc... Are mostly found in DBC files because that is the way Blizzard did it back in the day. It's true that in 2019 this is a pretty outdated way to work indeed. Databases are getting stronger and more versatile and having hard-coded data is proving to be hard to work with. Hell, DBCs aren't really that heavy anyways and the reason why we haven't made this change yet is that... We have no other reason other than it being a task that takes a bit of time and It is monotonous to do.

We are aware that Trinity core has already made this change but they have far more contributors than we do if that serves as an excuse!

Nonetheless, this is already in our to-do list if you check the issue tracker at the main repository.

While It's true that we can't really edit DBC files because we would lose all the progress when re-extracted or lost the files, however, we can modify spells in a C++ file called SpellMgr.

There we have a function called **SpellMgr::LoadDbcDataCorrections()**.

The main problem while doing this change is that we have to modify the core to support this change, and the function above contains a lot of corrections. Would need intense testing to make sure nothing is screwed up in the process.

In here by altering bits you can remove or add certain properties to the desired spells instead of touching the hard coded dbc files.

If you want an example, [in this link](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/1691/files#diff-f82ab5d79483dd6e1f5bd8c4d94299d3R4493), I have changed an Archimonde spell to have no cast time.

NOTE:
In this line, the commentary about damage can be miss leading but that's because I made a mistake and I haven't finished this pull request yet as of 18/04/2019.

Answer (score 2):

The work has been started, notably by Kaev. I think at least 3 DBCs are now useless server side (but probably still needed client side, they are called DataBaseClient for a reason) like item.dbc.

Also, the original philosophy (for ALL cores, not just AC) was that we would not touch DBC because we don't do custom modifications, so there was no interest in having them server side.

But we wanted to change this and started to make them available directly in the DB, if you wish to help with that, it would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

**Why?**

Because when emulation started, dbc fields were 90% unknown. So, developers created a parser for them that just required few code changes to support new fields as soon as their functionality was discovered.

Now that we've discovered 90% of required dbc fields and we've also created some great conversion tools for DBC<->SQL, it's just a matter of "effort".

SQL conversion is useful to avoid using of client data on server (you can totally overwrite them if you don't want to go against EULA) or just extends/customize them.

Here you are the issue about DBC->SQL conversion: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/584